# Вопрос по инкапсуляцию

Tags: ооп, php

В большинстве определений пишут, что мы должны предоставлять доступ к свойствам объекта
только через методы, а свойства сами по себе должны быть приватными.
Другими словами, при реализации класса - допустим, по отправке почты -, вместо того,
чтобы давать пользователю доступ к свойству yourmail напрямую, мы должны
создать метод типа `setYourMail($yourmail) {$this->yourmail = $yourmail}`, а само свойство объявить приватным. Вопрос, а какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если тебе вдруг понадобится изменить правила установки поля, ты сможешь устроить валидацию в этом сеттере. При этом не придется изменять клиентский код (как был вызов функции, им и остался).

Comment: это удобно, согласен, но как это связано с определением инкапсуляции? Ведь по сути это только сокрытие данных?

Comment: @Александр Железно...
С помощью сеттера вы управляете доступом к полю. А оно и вовсе может не существовать физически =) Например, надуманный пример: класс, представляющий обыкновенную дробь, с полем - числителем и знаменателем (оба они - целые числа). Вы можете сделать сеттер, который принимает одно дробное число, разбивает его на числитель и знаменатель и присваивает соответствующим полям. Аналогично эти значения "склеивает" в десятичную дробь геттер. А клиенту кажется, что там хранится просто десятичное дробное число. Вот тебе и "черный ящик", вот и сокрытие данных =)

Comment: >Ведь по сути инкапсуляция - это только сокрытие данных

@Александр Железно... задумайтесь над тем, для чего вообще нужно  сокрытие данных. И собственно для чего нужна инкапсуляция

Comment: @Александр Железно...
Или, скажем, значение сразу записывается в базу данных. Или кэшируется по пути. Но клиент об этом ничего не знает.

А будь у тебя обычное, тупое поле, попытайся прикрутить, скажем, проверку входных данных! Придется менять ВСЕ точки его использования.
Но это еще ладно. Использование таких функций позволяет реализовывать их по-разному в различных родственных классах. Вот тебе и полиморфизм.

Comment: Я приведу еще один пример про дробь: с сеттером хрен кто ноль в качестве делителя установит.